# Start program after a cell is made active

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a program that uses values within a certain column.

I want to select a cell, making it the active cell, to move the values into a formula.

I want the program to start after the cell is active without clicking another button. Basically the cell being active initiates the program.

I tried naming the program `private sub ActiveCell_click()`.

Comment: you want to look into the worksheet.SelectionChange event: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange But that will fire each time you select a new cell not when it goes into edit mode.

Comment: thanks that does exacly what i want, just one more question regarding this. Is there a way to limit it to only activate on a specific collum

Comment: yes, many examples using `If Not Intesect(Range("A:A"),Target) is Nothing Then`

Answer (score 0):

At worksheet code in dropmenu you can pick other options which could be a better then below, when will be big data you can meet so much lags.

[where you can check some more functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZS0Z.png)

Try it, maybe your app will not need much resources and it will work good :)
Or still didn't find nothing better:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_ActivateCell(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim selectedCells as Integer 
    Dim triggerCell as Range
    selectedCells = Selection.Count
    Set triggerCell = ActiveSheet.Range("F8").
    
 If selectedCells = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, triggerCell) Is Nothing Then
            Call CodeOfGodes
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```